# May I consider VisualVM as a Reference Implementation for NetBeans Platform?

Tags: user-interface, netbeans-platform

"Reference Implementation" for people (like me) how want to develop a modular, extensible, application on NetBeans Platform.

Link to [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) project

(Like [Stock Trader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921074%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) is a reference implementation for Microsoft Prisme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a reference Implementation then the [NetBeans IDE](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/) is about your best bet.

Another project that would be very worth looking at is [BlueMarine](http://bluemarine.tidalwave.it/), It's been around for a couple of years now and Fabrizio Giudici has really worked hard to make the project look different from the IDE.

**EDITED TO ADD**
There isn't an official Reference implementation in the manner that you speak of, and there has been discussion recently about adding more complex NetBeans platform samples.
See [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/more_complex_netbeans_platform_samples) and [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/more_complex_netbeans_platform_samples1)

Comment: :D you're right Tim. In fact, in my mind I was thinking about a "lighter" application, where it is possible to understand architectural choices, how each module is designed, cohesion, how java packages are organized, etc.

Comment: BlueMarine is a very good suggestion, but it was not developed by Oracle (Sun), like VisualVM is (which is also bundled with JDK)
http://www.trueknowledge.com/q/who_developed_visualvm

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of open source NetBeans Platform applications to look at:
http://platform.netbeans.org/screenshots.html

Comment: Thank you Geertjan. In fact, my question is more for experienced developers in NetBeans Platfom.
I want a critical opinion on the architecture, modularity and the application code.